# How to write an appium locator when we have no options other than bounds

Tags: appium-android

How to write xpath for the element with no options displayed in screenshot except bounds which is not recommended. What is the approach for such scenarios.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **content-desc** attribute from *Ui-automator*.If the element which you have to locate is static then you can use `findElementByXpath`. like :

```
driver.findElementByXpath(//*[@content-desc='My Time']).click();
```

And if the element is dynamic or the page in which you want to locate an element is dynamic but element is static then you can use `findElementByAndroidUIAutomator` for locating that element.

Hope this helps you.Thanks!

Comment: its is working with android 8.1 and not working for lower versions(7.1, 6 etc)